# Makefile to create an executable .mexa64 file from matlab

Tags: c, matlab, gcc, makefile

I try to write a makefile to create an executable .mexa64 file. I have to use the gcc compiler. My current working folder looks like this:

```
FFTW_build.c
FFTW_func.c 
Makefile.c  
obj (Folder, here are my object files *.o which are created)
```

**Source code FFTW_build.c:**

```
#include "mex.h"

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],  int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    FFTW_perform();
    return;
}
```

**Source code FFTW_func.c:**

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <complex.h>
#include <fftw3.h>
#include "mex.h"


void FFTW_perform() {

 int i;
 int Npoints=10;
 fftw_complex *in, *out;
 fftw_plan plan;

 in = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*Npoints);
 out = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*Npoints);
 plan = fftw_plan_dft_1d(Npoints, in, out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
 mexPrintf("\nCoefficcients of the expansion:\n\n");

 for(i = 0; i < Npoints; i++)
    {
        in[i] = (i+1)+(3*i-1)*I;
        mexPrintf("%d %11.7f %11.7f\n", i, creal(in[i]), cimag(in[i]));

    }

 mexPrintf("\n");

    fftw_execute(plan); 

    mexPrintf("Output:\n\n");
    for(i = 0; i < Npoints; i++)
    {
        mexPrintf("%d %11.7f %11.7f\n", i, creal(out[i]), cimag(out[i]));
    }
}
```

**Source code for Makefile.c:**

```
##################    Compiler    ##################
CXX = gcc 
####################################################

##################    MEXSUFFIX  ################
MEXSUFFIX  = mexa64  
####################################################

##################   Home of my matlab version #####
MATLABHOME = /home/tuebel/matlab
####################################################


##################    Object_File_Declaration_Folder    ################

OBJS_MEX       = FFTW_build.o
OBJS_FFTW_FUNC = FFTW_func.o 

ODIR=obj

_OBJ = $(OBJS_MEX) $(OBJS_FFTW_FUNC)
OBJ  = $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJ))


####################################################

##################    Header_Files    ################


# Header for mex 
DIR_MEX_HEADER = /home/tuebel/matlab/extern/include

_DEPS_MEX = mex.h
DEPS_MEX  = $(patsubst %,$(DIR_MEX_HEADER)/%,$(_DEPS_MEX))


# Header for fftw3
DIR_FFTW_HEADER = /usr/local/include

_DEPS_FFTW = fftw3.h
DEPS_FFTW  = $(patsubst %,$(DIR_FFTW_HEADER)/%,$(_DEPS_FFTW))


####################################################


##################    Library_Files    ################

# Libraries for mex
MEX_LIB  = /home/tuebel/matlab/bin/glnxa64/libmex.so   

# Libraries for FFTW
FFTW_LIB = /usr/local/lib/libfftw3.a

# Libraries for math_function
MATH_LIB = -lm 


####################################################

##################    Flags    ################

# MEXFLAGS         = -shared -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-rpath-link,$(MATLABHOME)/bin/glnxa64 -L$(MATLABHOME)/bin/glnxa64 -lmex -lmat -lmx -lm

MEXFLAGS         =  -shared -Wl,-rpath-link,$(MATLABHOME)/bin/glnxa64 -L$(MATLABHOME)/bin/glnxa64 -lmex -lmat -lmx -lm
COMPILERFLAGS    =  -fPIC -pthread -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -ansi -D_GNU_SOURCE -fno-omit-frame-pointer -O3 -DNDEBUG

FFTW_FLAGS_INCLUDE     = -I$(DIR_FFTW_HEADER)
MEX_FLAGS_INCLUDE      = -I$(DIR_MEX_HEADER)

####################################################

####################  Final_Part   ######################

TARGET = FFTW_MEX

all: $(TARGET) 
    echo ALL DONE

clean: 
    rm -f $(ODIR)/*.o 
    rm -f $(TARGET).mexa64
    echo CLEAN DONE


$(ODIR)/%.o: %.c $(DEPS_MEX) $(DEPS_FFTW)
    $(CXX) -c -o $@ $<  $(COMPILERFLAGS) $(MEX_FLAGS_INCLUDE) $(FFTW_FLAGS_INCLUDE)     

# Final_Linking

$(TARGET) : $(OBJ)  $(MATH_LIB) $(FFTW_LIB) 
    $(CXX) -o $@.$(MEXSUFFIX) $(MEX_FLAGS_INCLUDE) $(FFTW_FLAGS_INCLUDE) $^ $(MEXFLAGS) 


####################################################

####################################################

####################################################
```

The idea is to make a FFTW using fftw3. The code works fine in the command window, but if I try to make it executable from matlab (.mexa64 file) it is not working. I get the following error message using make:

```
gcc  -c -o obj/FFTW_build.o FFTW_build.c  -fPIC -pthread -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -ansi -D_GNU_SOURCE -fno-omit-frame-pointer -O3 -DNDEBUG -I/home/tuebel/matlab/extern/include -I/usr/local/include 
gcc  -c -o obj/FFTW_func.o FFTW_func.c  -fPIC -pthread -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -ansi -D_GNU_SOURCE -fno-omit-frame-pointer -O3 -DNDEBUG -I/home/tuebel/matlab/extern/include -I/usr/local/include 
gcc  -o FFTW_MEX.mexa64   -I/home/tuebel/matlab/extern/include -I/usr/local/include obj/FFTW_build.o obj/FFTW_func.o /usr/lib64/libm.so /usr/local/lib/libfftw3.a -shared -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/tuebel/matlab/bin/glnxa64 -L/home/tuebel/matlab/bin/glnxa64 -lmex -lmat -lmx -lm 
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libfftw3.a(lt4-problem.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib/libfftw3.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:92: recipe for target 'FFTW_MEX' failed
make: *** [FFTW_MEX] Error 1
```

Can someone help me out? This is my first Makefile and I would be glad for any help... I am also glad for corrections to the Makefile...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: For starters, Makefiles don't have a `.c` extension. Then, your `$@` is misplaced in your "final linking" rule, it belongs after `-o` (it is the output)

Comment: Now, I changed my code a little bit and I get the posted errors... How could I solve this?

Comment: I have no idea about matlab, maybe find some documentation there about *what exactly* a "mexa64" file *is*? Maybe it's a shared object and just adding `-shared` to the linking stage will do, but I really doubt it, you probably need some "special matlab linking"...

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit unclear what you mean by an "executable" .mexa64 file.

1. MATLAB's [mex compiler](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mex.html) will let you compile C/C++ code with MATLAB libraries into a mex file (with 64 bit architecture for you here) that you can then "execute" via MATLAB's command line.  This seems to be what you have gotten to work already.
2. However, if you want to have a stand alone "executable" outside of MATLAB, you need to work with MATLAB's mcr compiler (see the [reference here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler/mcc.html)).  There are flags that you can set in the process to be build an object file which you can then link with later on with your makefile as you are trying to now.

So, don't mix mex compiled files which are runnable within MATLAB and mcr compiled code that is executable outside of it.

Apart from this, gcc is complaining that there is no main() function.  I don't see one in your code here either, but you need a main() function for a standalone executable.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I need number 1. The main() function should be substituted by the mexFunction(). So the there should not be a main() function at all. So the mexFunction() has the functionality of the main() function.

Comment: If you need number 1, don't you already have it working then?  You will use 'mex' within MATLAB, not gcc.

Comment: You said, "The code works fine in the command window, but if I try to make it executable from matlab (.mexa64 file) it is not working."  I understand that to mean that you can get it work within the MATLAB command window (because you compiled it from mex), but the second part are you saying (a) You can't make it execute within MATLAB (contrary to what you just said) or (b) You can't build an executable from MATLAB (contrary to what you are trying to do with using a makefile and gcc).